# Java client calling WSE 2.0 with DIME attachment

Tags: java, .net, web-services, axis, ws-security

I need to integrate with a legacy .NET Web Service that uses WSE 2.0 for WS-Security and DIME. The catch is I need to do this from a Java application.

I'm expecting that Axis2 works fine with the WS-Security because folks around here have done it before. It's the DIME that I'm concerned about. I see a reference to DIME at http://ws.apache.org/axis/java/client-side-axis.html, but I'm wondering if anyone has actually done this with Axis and a WSE 2.0 Web Service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't tell you anything for sure from own expierence. And about every 2nd page on the "web" seems to state something different to this question.

So taking all together the following is all possible

1. Dime Support was dropped from 1.x to 2.x
2. Some kind of support in 2.x is there, possibly flaky
3. Support is there
4. No support at all is there
5. One of the provided links gives enough insight/code sample to get something useful going

Links to "Does Axis 2.0 support Dime"?

[No. You have to switch back to 1.4](http://www.mail-archive.com/axis-user@ws.apache.org/msg33083.html)

[No some guy](http://osdir.com/ml/axis-user-ws.apache.org/2009-05/msg00259.html)

[large attachments in dime format](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/ws-axis-user/200701.mbox/%3cBAY133-DAV468A5BA91D05A54768084AEB90@phx.gbl%3e) -> btw the same guy which 2009 states he never has heard of Dime since 2002

[Axis 1.x to Axis 2.1 port Dime](http://www.mail-archive.com/axis-user@ws.apache.org/msg21674.html) -> againThe same guy 2006 posting something which looks like a port

[Creating Apache Axis Java proxy classes that use DIME](http://livedocs.adobe.com/livecycle/8.2/programLC/programmer/help/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=sdkHelp&file=001510.html) From some Adobe Docu site

[J2EE Web Service Development with Attachments Using Axis](http://roseindia.net/webservices/web-services-development.shtml) -> The only real tutorial I found until now. But uses Axis 1.2.1

[AttachmentProblems](http://wiki.apache.org/ws/FrontPage/Axis/AttachmentProblems) -> An Axis Wiki page stating problems with Dime attachment files > 1 MB

Answer (score 1):

My investigation and experiments on this topic a year ago showed that Axis 2 doesn't supports DIME attachments despite the fact that there were some unclear notes in documentation and defines in the code. Now documentation is cleared up and there are no any notes on DIME support. But Axis 1.4 works with DIME attachments OK. Downgrade you Axis library to 1.4 if you can't force your partners to upgrade their service to support MTOM/XOP.

Answer (score -1):

WSE 2.0 is hopelessly obsolete. If you must continue on using obsolete software, then you should at least upgrade to WSE 3.0, which is somewhat less obsolete.

Comment: So how do I "make" business partners upgrade?  MS brewed the Kool Aid, now we must drink up! I'm doing a preemptive Googling for connecting to a WSE 2.0 service from Java, or at least Mono on *nix, and it looks like I'm in for another Microsoft sponsored shafting.  I suppose the Visual Studio crowd wishes the *nix crowd would go away, too.  **Sigh**

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about.  Please elaborate.