# Apache AXIS2 sending large DIME attachments

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis, webservice-client, attachment

I am currently working on a webservice to send large pdf files to server from client using DIME. I am using apache axis2 implementation for webservice support. I have been to get the service to work but an issue arises when I attempt to send attachments that are larger than 1MB then I get an exception. My guess is I probably would have to chunksize my attachment before sending it but I have no idea for where i can control that and also I am thinking maybe it would be another. Below is the code for the client that is uploading the files

```
public class PdfDriver
{

/**
 * @param args
 * @throws IOException
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    testAddGroup();

}

public static void testAddGroup() throws IOException
{

    try
    {
        PdfMail_ServiceLocator locator = new PdfMail_ServiceLocator();
             locator.setPdfMailSOAPEndpointAddress("http://localhost:80/services/PdfMailSOAP");

        PdfMail_PortType stub = locator.getPdfMailSOAP();

        PdfMailSOAPStub server = null;
        server = (PdfMailSOAPStub) stub;

        //Test uploading pdf
        server._setProperty(Call.ATTACHMENT_ENCAPSULATION_FORMAT,   Call.ATTACHMENT_ENCAPSULATION_FORMAT_MTOM);

        FileDataSource ds = new FileDataSource("/test.zip");
        DataHandler dh = new DataHandler(ds);

        server.addAttachment(dh);



        System.out.println(server.getTimeout());
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        long x = cal.getTimeInMillis();
        System.out.println("Server: Start receive@ "+  "\n" +   server.sendPdf("test.zip") + "\nServer: Finished receive ");



    }
    catch (ServiceException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


   }
}
```

And this is the code I use to process the attachments on the server side

```
public java.lang.String sendPdf(java.lang.String pdfToSend) throws java.rmi.RemoteException
{
    String result = "";
    AttachmentPart[] attachments = null;
    try
    {
        attachments = getAttachments();
    }
    catch (Exception e1)
    {
        result = "null attachments getAttachments exception";
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (attachments != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < attachments.length; i++)
        {
            AttachmentPart attachment = attachments[i];
            try
            {
                File file = new File(pdfToSend);
                InputStream in = attachment.getDataHandler().getInputStream();
                OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
                int len;

                while ((len = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
                    out.write(buffer, 0, len);

                out.close();
                in.close();

                result += "File saved on the server\nFile Size : " + (file.length() / 1048576) + "MB \nSend Type : " + this.receivedType;

            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                result += "exception IO";
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (SOAPException e)
            {
                result += "SOAP exception";
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}

private AttachmentPart[] getAttachments() throws Exception
{
    MessageContext msgContext = MessageContext.getCurrentContext();
    Message message = msgContext.getRequestMessage();
    Attachments attachmentsimpl = message.getAttachmentsImpl();
    if (null == attachmentsimpl)
    {
        return new AttachmentPart[0];
    }
    int attachmenstCount = attachmentsimpl.getAttachmentCount();
    this.receivedType = attachmentsimpl.getSendType();
    AttachmentPart attachments[] = new AttachmentPart[attachmenstCount];

    Iterator<AttachmentPart> iter = attachmentsimpl.getAttachments().iterator();
    int count = 0;
    while (iter.hasNext())
    {
        AttachmentPart part = iter.next();
        attachments[count++] = part;
    }
    return attachments;

}
```

If anyone knows what the issue would be causing an AxisFault for files larger that 1MB I would appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: The code shown isn't using Axis2, but Axis 1.x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Axis2 does not support DIME, see previous question:
[Java client calling WSE 2.0 with DIME attachment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004586/java-client-calling-wse-2-0-with-dime-attachment)

Answer (score 0):

Knowing exactly what the exception is would help, but to just blindly guess, your Apache config is probably limiting upload (http post) size.